# Short Circuiting: How would I write if then else with short-circuiting?

Tags: if-statement, pseudocode, short-circuiting

> Is it possible to write a one-line `if then else` statement in a language that supports short-circuiting? It doesn't have to be language specific, just pseudocode.

In case you didn't know, short-circuiting means that a language will evaluate `exp1 || exp2 || exp3 || exp4...` (`||` is the `or` operator) by first **executing** `exp 1`, then if it returns true, **execute** `exp 2`, and so on... However, the moment `exp n` returns false, it does not continue evaluating `exp n+1` and anything after that.

Comment: It will work in C and C++ for sure.  Have a look at this for a full list of languages: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to express:

```
if p then f() else g()
```

Using only || and &&, both short circuiting. You can do that like this:

```
(p && ( f() || 1 )) || g()
```

To test it, a quick script:

```
$ perl -E '$p=1; ($p && ( f() || 1 )) || g(); sub f { say "f() called" } sub g { say "g() called" }'
f() called
$ perl -E '$p=0; ($p && ( f() || 1 )) || g(); sub f { say "f() called" } sub g { say "g() called" }'
g() called
$
```

Comment: Interesting, but what if *p* is `true` and *f()* is `false`? Wouldn't *g()* be evaluated?

Comment: @watery Yes, you are right, it should say ( f() || 1 ) - I will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

In C, C++, C# and Java, you can do this (all 4 support short circuiting):

```
a = a>b ? a : b;
```

This would assign `a` the bigger of the two, either `a` or `b`.

This is called the `ternary operator`. First comes the condition to test `a>b`, then a question mark, then the `true` value (e.g. `a`), then a colon, then the `false` value (e.g. `b`).

Comment: I'd say you can't; you're using a different operator, aren't you here? And, BTW, where's the short circuitry?

Comment: @watery - In C, C++, C# and Java, short circuiting automatically occurs.

Comment: I know, I meant I don't understand where the short circuitry could happen in your example.

Comment: @watery I guess short circuiting for the ternary operator means that either the part after the ? gets executed or the part after the :, but not both. It is probably clearer if you think of an example like a>b ? f() : g() - either f() or g() gets called, but not both.

Comment: @asjo I still don't see the short circuitry there: to my understanding, that's how the ternary operator behaves, and that behaviour doesn't depend on short cirtuitry being available in the language.

Comment: @watery short circuiting for "a() || b()" means that b() will ONLY be called if a() is false. If || didn't short circuit, then both a() and b() would be called, before evaluating the ||. I was just guessing that what was meant was something similar to that. But you're right it doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't by simply short circuitry. That's meant to shorten the number of conditions being evaluated by skipping all conditions after the first that would make the whole condition `true` or `false` (based on the operator).

E.g.:

```
boolean x = true || 1 == 2;
```

The `||` evalutation won't check the value of `1 == 2`, since `true` will already turn the `||` true, no matter what follows.

In a similar way for `&&`:

```
boolean y = 2 < 3 && 5 > 6;
```

To expand a bit on that, I could write:

```
boolean y = 2 < 3 && 5 > func();
```

In either case, the second half of the condition won't be checked (and func() won't be invoked) because the first half gives `false`.

There's no way to do something `else`, only with this behaviour.

Comment: If you are allowed to use both || and &&, you can.